# Como puedo mostrar los datos en una DataTable JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, php, laravel

El promblema que tengo es que quiero mostrar datos, es decir cargarlos en una DataTable pero no entiendo que estoy haciendo mal. el mensaje que me muestra es el siguiente:

> DataTables warning: table id=patientsTable - Ajax error. For more information about this error, please see http://datatables.net/tn/7

Comment: Hola! Bienvenidx a SOes. 
Las preguntas del tipo "Tengo que hacer esto" sin mostrar el código que has escrito no suelen ser bien recibidas, ya que la respuesta será siempre adivinando y no encaja en el formato del sitio.
Recomiendo que hagas el [recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para entender el sitio y de paso ganar tu primera medalla. 
También estaría bien que revisaras [Cómo preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para que recibas respuesta cuanto antes.

Comment: No tenemos idea de cuál será el código que genera ese error. Añade el código relevante donde intentas cargar los datos en el datatable. Recuerda que puedes [edit] tu pregunta cuantas veces sea necesario (incluso si termina cerrada) y añadir la info relevante a forma de [Ejemplo mínimo](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) (en los comentarios no se ve bien el código y abajo sólo van nuestros intentos de respuesta).

Comment: Hola Javier, bienvenido, para poder ayudarte, necesitamos ver tu código, edita tu pregunta y agregalo en formato texto (solo la parte involucrada en tu problema, y de ser posible que se pueda ejecutar).